# Jquery terminal cursor is hidden in FF upon pressing left arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-terminal

I am using jquery 2.4.1 and adding a terminal window. In firefox I am facing an issue , the cursor is disappearing when I navigate using left arrow. It re-appears if I press enter. Other browsers it works fine.

Saw there was a bug (fix hidden cursor in FireFox) in jquery 2.4.1 and is fixed in 2.5.0 as per changelog https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Can we get a patch for the fix? Or any workaround?

Css applied is same in working condition and non working condition
class="cursor blink"

Comment: How about loading 2.5.0 instead of 2.4.1 ..?

Comment: The fix is in CSS you get get the diff from GitHub https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/commit/d4f936310edf26e0de45e4aae81323697611c15c or you can just download new css  file there are not many changes in CSS.